# É possível combinar URLs?

Tags: c#, .net, url

O `Path.Combine()` junta partes de um caminho de arquivo em uma coisa só. Seria possível usar URLs e juntar, algo, assim?

```
Url.Combine("http://dominio.com.br/", )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tratar de URLs usamos a classe [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E o construtor possui uma forma que faz a concatenação das partes:

```
 Uri myUri = new (new Uri("http://dominio.com.br/"), "/Imagens/Imagem.png");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Uri.cs).